# Showing Null Pointer Exception When Calling function from another class Android

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I have a class called car which is implements the `LocationListerner class(default class)` inside a `GoodActivity Class`. so the `Car class` having a function named `onLocationChanged()`. Inside the `onLocationChanged()` function I called the function named `fun()` which is static function of another class called Contact3. when calling a function `fun()` I got a *Null Pointer Exeptional error*.

`fun()` function called the `posts()` method which is in another class called *SongsActivity*.

GoodActivity Class

```
  public class GoodActivity extends Activity {
  Button button2;
  good s;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_good);         
    }

  public class car implements LocationListener{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {           
         try{
             String name="vijay";           
             Contact3.fun(GoodActivity.this,name);
             }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(GoodActivity.this, e.toString()+"good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }}}}
```

Contact3 Class

```
  public class Contact3 {
  public static void fun(Context context,String name) { 
  SongsActivity s=new SongsActivity();
  s.posts(name);    
  }
  }
```

SongsActivity Class

```
    public class SongsActivity extends Activity {
    public void posts(String name){     
    try {
    Log.d("Tests", s);`
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(SongsActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }}}
```

when calling a function `fun()` i got a *Null Pointer Exeptional error*.

Please Help.

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: you can not make `Toast` with non visible activity. `SongsActivity` not a visible one, but you tried to show `Toast` using `SongsActivity.this`

Comment: you can't create instance of Activity class, you get NPE because context of activity is null, if you want toast message from other class you must pass `Context` to that class

Answer (score 2):

> SongsActivity s=new SongsActivity();

Line causing issue because you are trying to use `SongsActivity.this` context without starting Activity. if `SongsActivity` is normal java class then no need to extends Activity. you can show Toast by passing Context from `fun` to `posts`.

Do it as:

**1.** Remove extends Activity from `SongsActivity`

**2.** Add one more argument in posts method as Context:

```
 public void posts(String name,Context context){     
        try {
           Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } catch (Exception e) {

         }
       }
```

**3.** Pass Context from `fun` method:

```
  SongsActivity s=new SongsActivity();
  s.posts(name,context);
```

Comment: without removing extends activity from songsactivity is possible? i dont want remove the activity...

Comment: @Good: let me know why you not want to remove `extends Activity`?

Comment: In this activity there is some user interaction for some registration... whether it is possible without removing activity?

Comment: @Good: then create separate normal java class and add `posts` method then you can access `posts` method from both Activity classes.

Comment: thats ok... in this above code it is possible to access the function with  activity?

Comment: @Good: yes if you remove `extends Activity`